# get the date - 3 months

Tags: javascript, postman

I'm trying to get the current date - 3 months and use it in a postman Pre-request script. I'm told it uses javascript, but it doesn't seem to be working.

The error I get is:

> There was an error in evaluating the Pre-request Script:  TypeError:
>   startDate.setMonth is not a function

Here is what I have:

```
// setup start date
var startDate =  Date();
startDate.setMonth(startDate.getMonth() - 3);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Syntax

> JavaScript Date objects can only be instantiated by calling JavaScript Date as a constructor: calling it as a regular function (i.e. without the new operator) will return a string rather than a Date object; unlike other JavaScript object types, JavaScript Date objects have no literal syntax.

so

```
Date();
```

needs to be

```
new Date();
```

Comment: thanks, postman turns the new red, so assumed the syntax was bad, also the error is missleading

Answer (score 1):

Try change `var startDate = Date();` to `var startDate = new Date();`

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, Postman comes with the [moment](http://momentjs.com/docs/) module built in so you could do something like this:

```
var moment = require("moment")
var startTime = moment().subtract(3, 'months')
```

Or you could obviously use native JavaScript, worth knowing a couple of different ways though.